# kcat get latest message from a topic with a specified key

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

I am doing integration tests for Kafka and I produce a message with a key `integration-test-sub-key` and I want to read it later and compare result to what is expected.

I tried doing

```
$ kcat -b localhost:9092 -t topic-name -C -o -1 -c 1 -k integration-test-sub-key
```

to filter the message by `integration-test-sub-key` key, but it doesn't work.

How to do this? Do I need to use grep or something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use `grep`.

Kafka topics are not indexed by key. You need to scan the whole topic using `-o earliest`, not `-o -1`, as that means one offset from the end, then remove `-c 1`.

Also, `-k <value>` is only a producer option, not a valid consumer flag.

---

If this is a use-case you want to use often, then use ksqlDB, or Kafka Streams to create a KTable, where you have all keys with their latest values.